# SwiftUI - Mutable @FocusState for child view?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, ios15

I have a parent view with a `@FocusState` variable that I want to pass into a child view that contains a `TextField`. I want to be able to change the `FocusState` from within the child view, but I get the errors `Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable` and `Cannot assign value of type 'Bool' to type 'FocusState<Bool>.Binding'`.

Parent view:

```
struct ParentView: View {
    @State private var text: String
    @FocusState private var isEditing: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ChildView($text, $isEditing)
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    var isEditing: FocusState<Bool>.Binding
    
    init(_ text: Binding<String>, _ isEditing: FocusState<Bool>.Binding) {
        self._text = text
        self.isEditing = isEditing
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Username", text: $text)
            .focused(isEditing)
        
        Button("Click me!") {
            isEditing = false  // Error here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just assign via binding to wrapped value, like

```
Button("Click me!") {
    isEditing.wrappedValue = false  // << here !!
}
```

Comment: Works! Is there any way I can have isEditing only appear for that particular `TextField`? When I have multiple ChildViews and tap one it triggers it on every item, not just the one in focus.

Comment: Disregard my last comment, I was able to achieve this with the `equals:` focused parameter